# ASP.NET MVC Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm having this strange routing problem - I have 2 kinds of routes to the same view. Such as *Simulator/RunStrategy/7* and *Simulator/RunStrategy/7/1000*.

Where as the controller and view is defined as *public ActionResult RunStrategy(int id, decimal sum)*.

When I use the short one I see the view as needed, when i use the long one - I get all the "link href...." messed up.
Such as:

`<link href="../../../css/global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Where it should be:

`<link href="../../css/global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Which really is displayed correctly when I use the short routing link.

The routing table is as follows:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Run Simulation",
            "Simulator/RunStrategy/{id}/{startingsum}",
            new { controller = "Simulator", action = "RunStrategy", id = "0", startingsum = "100000" },
            new { id = @"\d+", startingsum = @"^([0-9]*|\d*\.\d{1}?\d*)$" }
        );
```

Where it works fine.

Help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How are linking your CSS files? Are you using Url.Content()?

Comment: Should I? I'm using direct links as given above (for the short route version) and it is being added "../" at the long route for some reason.

Comment: have you thought about simply using root path, e.g. /themes/css/global.css?

Comment: for some strange reason it just doens't work. It needs those "../../" to work - where it really should accept the root path. ideas why so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using Url.Content() and see if that makes a difference.

Example:

```
<link href="<%=Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: I've tried that one - it gives me a link to "/css/global.css" where it should be "../../css/global.css"

Comment: BTW - the problem is only with CSS files. for JS it works fine.

Comment: What is the full path of your global.css file?

Comment: it's at the root of the site with /css/global.css (i.e <root>/css/global.css) - where as the directories are standard MVC dir structure.

Comment: If /css/global.css is the full path of your file, and the Url.Content() outputs <link href="/css/global.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />, then it should work from every page because it's using an absolute url instead of a relative one. Are you sure there isn't some other problem?

Comment: That's what I've thought - but it seems it's the only problem. If I use the same path but add ../../ - it works. though if I view source and try to go the css file - it works BOTH times. so I seems the browser is able to see the files everytime but doesn't use them for some reason.

Comment: I've found the problem... I wrote "ref" instead of "rel"... so sorry for the trouble and thank you VERY much for your help!

Comment: the Url.Content was the answer :)